# How to use a mysql variable from one table as a subquery in another, but casting it as a string (from int)

Tags: mysql, subquery

This is the query i'm trying to run:

```
UPDATE files set refcount=
   (
      SELECT count(*) 
      FROM comments WHERE data=files.id
   ) 
   WHERE id=?;
```

The problem is, *comments.data* is a text column (for other reasons). So I need to cast *files.id* as a STRING instead of what it is (an INT), because otherwise the *comments.data* index won't be used.

For example, this query runs fine:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE data='1234';
```

But this one takes forever (because it cannot use the index, comments has 10M rows):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE data=1234;
```

Perhaps I need to use @vars or something? I tried putting the thing in quotes, but that uses the literal "files.id" i think.

```
UPDATE files set refcount=
   (
      SELECT count(*) 
      FROM comments WHERE data='files.id'
   ) 
   WHERE id=?;
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to cast files.id into string before comparing it to data

something like this :

```
UPDATE files set refcount=
   (
      SELECT count(*) 
      FROM comments WHERE data=CAST(files.id AS vachar)
   ) 
   WHERE id=?;
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)'s a link that show how you can use cast functions and operators in mysql.

**UPDATED:** It seems that for some reasons CAST is not working with varchar.Though char might do the trick (whih in case it doesn't as Timh said in the comments below) CONCAT can be used to convert other types to a varchar (when you concat othery types with a string it returns a string and concating with an empty string will act as some sort of conversion :) )

Comment: that makes total sense, but for some reason doesn't work (according to docs its "char" not "varchar"). I tried with CAST(files.id as char), and CAST(files.id as char(12)). Same result... query takes forever.  Seems like your solution should work though?!

Comment: Got it to work by using concat. WHERE data=CONCAT(files.id,''). Go ahead and add that to your answer and i'll mark it correct. thanks.

Comment: if it takes too long or s not working due to a time out exception maybe you are facing some performance issues.BTW I didn't know that CAST doesn't support varchar which is very strange.maybe ypu can CAST data az int (if there are all digits) and see it it works

Comment: Strange usage of CONCAT though :))